# imitating a string to look like a byte - python

Tags: python, python-requests

i'm trying to create some sort of a code that takes images online and converts them into files as a part of a project im making.
I got into a problem where i get a string that looks like the bytes you need to write in a file but I cant manage to put it as a byte
Ive tried to do a normal 'w' but it wont work and I tried to do bytes(str(r.content), 'utf-8') but it wont work either
is there a way it can be done?

```
import requests
x = input("enter url/path: ")
r = requests.get(x)
print(r.content)
with open("test."+x.split('.')[-1], "wb") as f:
    f.write(str(r.content))
```

error:

```
    f.write(str(r.content))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `r.contents` is *already* a `bytes` object!  From the [`requests` documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

> You can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:
>
> > *>>>* r.content b'[{"repository":{"open_issues":0,"url":"https://github.com/...

So the easy way out is to simply drop the `str()`:

```
f.write(r.content)
```

Now in the comments you seem to really want to work with actual strings instead of bytes.  There are many good reasons to want to do that, so I won't judge.  But `requests` has you covered there too - it already does the conversion and makes it available as `r.text`!

A file can be opened two different ways: text or binary.  It depends on whether you have the `"b"` character in the `open` call.  If you leave out the `b`, it will accept a string instead of a bytes-like object.

```
with open("test."+x.split('.')[-1], "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

Note that I also added an `encoding` parameter which is required to allow the conversion of strings to file bytes properly.

It turns out that `str(r.content)` is the wrong way to convert bytes to a string.  Let me show you a little demonstration:

```
>>> def whatis(x):
    print(type(x), len(x), x)

>>> whatis(r'a\b')
<class 'str'> 3 a\b
>>> whatis(rb'a\b')
<class 'bytes'> 3 b'a\\b'
>>> whatis(str(rb'a\b'))
<class 'str'> 7 b'a\\b'
```

The proper way to do it is with `decode()`:

```
>>> whatis(rb'a\b'.decode())
<class 'str'> 3 a\b
```

You probably don't want to do that though because you need to know how the contents were encoded to pass as a parameter to `.decode()`, and `r.text` has done the same thing for you already.

Comment: it now writes something to the file but it swaps every '\' with 2 '\' (like '\\') and the file now cant be loaded

Comment: @avi maybe you should try `f.write(r.content)`.

Comment: The entire point in the question is to take a string that's the r.content, in my project I get the r.content as a string and I need to put it in a file so I can't just write r.content I basically have no choice

Comment: @avi I had assumed that `str` on a `bytes` object converted it directly to a string, but I just discovered that's wrong and it behaves like `repr` instead.  That's the problem, particularly why you get the doubled backslashes.  You need to use `r.contents.decode()` instead, preferably with a parameter that indicates the encoding of the source bytes.

Comment: @avi I've almost completely rewritten the answer, check it and see if it doesn't address all your concerns.

Comment: ty for the help, the program works now.
sry for bothering you with the getting a string but my project is basically a socket based chat and if I want to get a picture from like another computer i get the bytes of the picture so the code was just an example of this part, i found it easier to just send the hyper link for the server to download but i still needed the solution for the picture by itself
anyways, again sorry for misunderstandings and have a great day